# How to start activity 5 minutes after exiting an app?

Tags: android

I'm looking for a solution on how to make sort of an alarm that after exiting an app it will start a new activity (or ten minutes if a user chooses to). It would be non-repeating, just one time.

I looked at TimerTask and Handlers, but they seem to be working only when an app is in the foreground. AlarmManager looks like it could do the job, but I don't know how to approach that. Any suggestions?

**edit1:**
So here is what I have in MainActivity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("wake_up");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 5000, pendingIntent);
```

This is BroadcasReceiver:

```
 @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setClassName("(packagename)", "(whole class name)");
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```

And how I registered it in Manifest (like other activities):

```
<receiver
        android:name="FakeCallBroadcastReceiver" >
    </receiver>
```

I have put Toast in BroadcastReceiver and it works, but it appears immediately - changing time from 5000 to let's say 10000 doesn't change anything.

Comment: have you seen PendingIntent?

Comment: try this url
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

Answer (score 3):

Add this in `onCreate()` method in `Application` instance or main `Activity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("wake_up");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 5000, pendingIntent);
```

and start `Activity` in `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       context.startActivity(...);
   }
}
```

Register the `BroadcastReceiver` with intent filter:

```
<receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="wake_up" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Maybe consider changing the receiver name to AlarmReceiver instead of BluetoothAdapterReceiver, just so it makes more sense.

Comment: I have updated my question - something is still missing though

Comment: @mklimek I changed it to alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeToCall, pendingIntent); and now work fine :) I don't why RTC_WAKEUP didn't went through though. P.S. Miło widzieć polski akcent na stacku ;)

Comment: @jeand'arme tak właśnie pomsyślałem, że zapewne to wina RTC_WAKEUP. Pozdrowienia :)

Answer (score 2):

Alarm manager is definitely the way to go.  You'll need to have a broadcast receiver to receive the alarm, and then set a pending intent in that receiver.

As you mentionned, TimerTask and Handlers won't help you much here.

The easiest way to go with a broadcast receiver is to register it in the android manifest as a broadcast receiver.  You can also register them manually, but it's a bit harder conceptually.

Have fun!